# OpenCV error : Assertion failed ((img.depth() == CV_8U || img.depth() == CV_32F)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing

When i try to run this code in Visual Studio 2010 from [here](http://www.technolabsz.com/2013/05/eye-blink-detection-using-opencv-in.html). i am getting the following error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((img.depth() == CV_8U || img.depth() == CV_32F)
&& img.type() == templ.type()) in cv::matchTemplate, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\mod
ules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp, line 249
An exception occured
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't load images successfully. So make sure you pass in images correctly by setting `argv[]`. Pay attention to the following lines of the code:

```
   if(argc <= 1)  
      {  
      std::cout<<"\n Help "<<std::endl;  
      std::cout<<"\n ------------------------------------\n"<<std::endl;  
      std::cout<<"./blink_detect open_eye.jpg close_eye.jpg\n"<<std::endl;  
     std::cout<<"Eg :: ./blink_detect 2.jpg 3.jpg\n"<<std::endl;  
      std::cout<<"\n ------------------------------------\n"<<std::endl;  
      exit(0);  
      }   
    ... ...
    img1 = imread( argv[1], 1 );  
    img2 = imread( argv[2], 1 );
```

---

**Edit**: You can set `argv[]` in two ways:

1. Through project's command arguments:

   `Project > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Command Arguments > 2.jpg 3.jpg`
2. Directly in the source code:

   ```
   argc = 3;
   argv[1] = "2.jpg";
   argv[2] = "3.jpg";
   ```

Comment: I m giving the arguements via command line arguments to this application, its like

'code'blink_detect.exe 2.jpg 3.jpg' at the debugging panel of project properties in visual studio

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi You only need to give `2.jpg 3.jpg` if you set project properties in VS. The first argument will be generated automatically.

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi I have added how to set `argv[]` in the answer.